# Как посчитать легкий пример?

Tags: ассемблер

Не получается посчитать пример
Определить номер (n) элемента последовательности an = 3* n^2 – 5 * n + 12, при котором сумма элементов последовательности превысит 1500
По идее в конце N должна быть = 12.
Код неправильно работает, я думаю из-за возведения в степень. Прошу помощи

```
    int main()          // начало программы на языке С++
{
    long    N = 0;      // ячейка памяти для аргумента
    long    S = 0;      // ячейка для хранения суммы
    long    P = 1;      // ячейка для накопления 8n 
    long kv = 2;
    long tri = 3;

    _asm
    {; начало ассемблерной вставки
        m1 : inc    N;// увеличение аргумента
        //mov   EBX, 3;// EBX = 3
        mov EAX, P;// ECX = n(1)
        mul kv;
        mul tri; 
        mov P, EAX; // 3*n^2 in P
        add S, EAX;// накопление суммы
        
        mov EAX, 5;// EAX = 5
        mul N;// EAX = 5 * n
        sub S, EAX;// накопление суммы

        mov EAX, N;// EAX = n
        add EAX, 12;
        add S, EAX;

        cmp S, 1500;// сравнение суммы с 1500
        jc  m1;// переход, если сумма меньше 1500
    }
}
```

Comment: Считаете с++ не справится лучше с этой задачей?

Comment: @vp_arth задание состоит именно в написании этого на ассемблере

Comment: напишите программу на c++, в дебаге остановите программу и вызовите из меню disassenbler :)

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что правильный ответ 12?

Comment: Я беру функцию, и в экселе сначала подставляю вместо n 1, получаю результат и плюсую его к сумме. Потом считаю еще раз функцию, где n=2, результат плюсую к сумме. Получается при n=1 res=10, при n=2 res=14. И потом смотрю на каком значении n сумма станет больше 1500. Вроде я так понял

Comment: Аха, мы оба элемент>1500 нашли вместо суммы)

Comment: ну мне кажется задание в том, что нужно найти шаг, на котором сумма становится > 1500. По моим расчетам это 12 шаг.

Comment: Обновил свой ответ

Answer (score 1):

Член последовательности, для простоты, можно представить как (3n-5)*n + 12

Решение для суммы ряда:

```
asm (
    "xor ebx, ebx;"           // sum = 0;
    "xor ecx, ecx;"           // n = 0;
    "it:"                     // do {
    "lea eax, [ecx+ecx*2];"   //   an = (3*n
    "sub eax, 5;"             //             - 5)
    "mul ecx;"                //                  * n
    "add eax, 12;"            //                      + 12;

    "add ebx, eax;"           //   sum += an;

    "cmp ebx, 1500;"          //   if (sum > 1500)
    "jg res;"                 //     break;
    "inc ecx;"                //   ++n;

    "jmp it;"                 // } while (true);
    "res:mov %0, ecx;"

    : "=r" (dst) // 12
);
```

[Решение](https://godbolt.org/z/n3Wr9h) от компилятора.

---

Ниже решение не той задачи. Ищет член превышающий 1500 :(

```
// g++ -masm=intel tmp.cpp -o /tmp/tmp && /tmp/tmp
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    int dst;
    // an = 3* n^2 – 5 * n + 12, an > 1500
    // (3n-5)*n + 12
    asm (
        "xor ecx, ecx;"
        "it:"                   // do {
        "lea eax, [ecx+ecx*2];" // an =(3*n
        "sub eax, 5;"           //         -5)
        "mul ecx;"              //            *n
        "add eax, 12;"          //              +12;

        "cmp eax, 1500;"        // if (an > 1500)
        "jg res;"               //     break;
        "inc ecx;"              // ++n;
        "jmp it;"               // } while (True);

        "res: mov %0, ecx;"

        : "=r" (dst)
    );

    printf("%d\n", dst); // 24
}
```

[Посмотрел](https://godbolt.org/z/Mfq3Wx), что GCC генерирует на код выше в комментариях, что-то вроде:

```
asm (
    "mov DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 0;"
    "mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0;"

    ".L_1: mov edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-4];" 
    "mov eax, edx;"                     
    "add eax, eax;"                     
    "add eax, edx;"                     
    "sub eax, 5;"
    "imul eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4];"
    "add eax, 12;"
    "mov DWORD PTR [rbp-8], eax;"
    "cmp DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 1500;"
    "jg .L_2;"
    "add DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1;"
    "jmp .L_1;"
    ".L_2: mov %0, DWORD PTR [rbp-4];"

    : "=r" (dst)
);
```

я на 3 умножаю интереснее))

Comment: Теперь нужен замер производительности, чей ассемблер быстрее)

Comment: Ну, разве что за счёт отсутствия работы с памятью(исправляется одним словом register) может выиграть мой. А так, тут аксиома Эскобара. Любые замерялки внесут больше энтропии))

Comment: `я на 3 умножаю интереснее` компилятор со включенной оптимизации редко оставляет людишкам шанс покрасоваться.[-O3](https://godbolt.org/z/5rsnKv) [-Os](https://godbolt.org/z/E3x4Yf) :)

Comment: Допустим, сумма ряда = `n((n+1)(n-2)+12)` можно ли оценить `n` с которого следует начинать?

Comment: @extrn Куда нам, кожаным мешкам)

Comment: @vp_arth, на 3 интереснее умножать в ARM архитектуре  - `add r0, r0, lsl 1`

Comment: @Zhihar, в архитектуре [Сетунь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%8C_(%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80)) думаю всего лишь сдвиг влево.

Answer (score 0):

```
int res = 0;

__asm {

    mov ecx, 0      ; счётчик n 
    mov edx, 0      ; счётчик суммы

    calc_loop:
    
    mov eax, ecx    ; вычисляем 5n
    mov esi, 5
    mul esi
    mov ebx, eax

    mov eax, ecx    ; вычисляем 3n^2
    mul ecx
    mov esi, 3
    mul esi

    sub eax, ebx    ; вычисляем 3n^2 - 5n + 12
    add eax, 12

    add edx, eax    ; увеличиваем сумму

    inc ecx         ; увеличиваем n

    cmp edx, 1200   ; если сумма менее 1200 выполняем этап вычислений еще раз
    jl calc_loop

    mov res, ecx
}

std::cout << res << std::endl;
```

так?

Comment: Написали на С++, а потом отладчиком посмотрели чего там компилятор нагенерил? :)

Comment: @Джонни Кэтсвилл, по памяти написал, все напутал, но уже переделал :)

Comment: @Zhihar не запускается такое(

Comment: @Кирилл Реука, внес изменения

Comment: @Zhihar код рабочий, но у вас ошибка, не 1200, а 1500. Но если в коде поменять на 1500, то ответ неверный показывает. Должно быть 12 или 13. А у Вас 25. Но все равно спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: можно улучшить и начинать с определенного n, формула суммы есть.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, доводить до `cout << 12;` всё же, наверное, не стоит.

Comment: @vp_arth, шучу)